# How do I remove a Firestore snapshot listener from a Vuex store

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex4

I am trying to figure out how to remove a snapshot listener from my vue3/vuex store.  I have seen the answers to other similar questions and the many links to the Firestore docs, but I cannot figure out WHERE in the vuex store to put the call to unsubscribe().  Could someone help with where and how to call the unsubscribe() function while using vuex?

I have a component that is calling to the bindAccts() in the store, which then runs a commit/mutation and populates my "accounts state.  Here is the code I have in my vuex store file:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { db } from '../main'

export default createStore({
  state() {
    return { categories: [], accounts: [], transactions: [], count: 1 }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_ACCTS(state, data) {
      state.accounts = data
    },

  },
  actions: {
    bindAccts({ commit }) {
      this.unsubscribe = db
        .collection('accounts')
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
          let accounts = []
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            accounts.push(doc.data())
          })
          commit('SET_ACCTS', accounts)
        })
    },
...
```

Inside my test component I am calling bindAccts() like this and just quickly displaying the accounts state on the ui:

```
<template>
  <button @click="bindAccts">Subscribe</button>
  <button @click="unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
  <p>Accounts: {{ accounts }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  components: {},

  data() {
    return {}
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({ accounts: state => state.accounts })
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['bindAccts', 'unsubscribe'])
  }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

Doing this I am unable to find the unsubscribe function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

#### Return `unsubscribe` function from action and call in component

1. In your Vuex action, return the `unsubscribe` from `bindAccts({ commit })`.
2. In your component, for the Subscribe button `onClick` handler function (a new one), you call the `bindAccts` and store the returned function in local `data` or a variable.
3. Then, when the user clicks Unsubscribe, you call the local stored `unsubscribe` if defined.

Or

#### Save `unsubscribe` in your Vuex store

1. The idea would be to save the `unsubscribe` variable in your existing Vuex store as a state variable and use `Getters` and `Mutations` to get/set the variable (same as other properties in your current state).
2. Then, you can add `unsubscribe` as another Vuex action, and in your component, use `mapActions` to map the action as a method. The logic would be quite straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am running into an error when trying to implement your first solution.  I return the result of calling the bindAccts() and populate the "unsubscribe" under my local data.  Vue devtools shows it is populated as a "Promise".  I then try to call unsubscribe via the button and get the response "Uncaught TypeError: $data.unsubscribe.apply is not a function."  I think I am getting closer and love the logic you suggested but still need to resolve how to handle calling unsubscribe successfully.

Comment: @Soundpeck According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener I think `unsubscribe` shouldn't be a Promise, but a function instead? Anyway, if you're certain that you're returning `unsubscribe` and it's a Promise, then you can try `async/await` syntax.

Comment: Another thing is that you can use Vue debugger or console to print out what `$data.unsubscribe` is in your component local state, to confirm nothing unexpected happens

Comment: Thanks for all of the help!  I did have to change a few other things but this definitely got me headed in the correct direction.